# prevent api call from diffrent clients at the same time

Tags: nestjs

iam using google calendar api in my project to make a calander to handel clients Appointments .
iam using nestjs as a backend for my project but I have encountered a certain problem while inserting appointments which is that i have a simple validation that a client cannot book an appointment if this appointment is reserved for another client .
the problem is if 2 useres pressed the button (book date) from 2 diffrent devices at the same time the function will book for them at the same time so there will be two appointments at the same time for two different clients and the more the device increase the more the appoinments for diffrent ckients at the ssame time will increase .
I know it's a slight possibility, but it does happen, so I'd like to know how to prevent something like this knowing that iam using async function to book the dates

``

i searched for any thing to prevent it but couldnt find something , I may not be able to search well

Comment: looks like you need to implement some sort of locking. The simplest way that I can think of is that lock the resource at your database level it will stop 2 process to access the same resource.

Comment: in my case there is no database level because the google calender api   create the appointments i need on google servers i have no data base i cant insert delete update or list appointments on a specific calender i created on google calender so there is no database level

Comment: easiest way for your usecase would be to use in-memory cache, NestJS supports it out of the box - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching
you can set the key to be your date, and check against it